# Lightning out error - "Unable to read the Aura token from the response"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-out, node.js

I'm currently working on a LWC embbeded in Aura with Lightning out and my component is on error since this morning with `Uncaught Error: Unable to read the Aura token from the response`.
[image]

The connection is successful as I can see on the user log
[image]

I dont understand because all was working good yesterday.

For more detail, I made it work with nodeJs following Andres Perez tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@ElToroIT/lightning-web-components-support-lightning-out-5a79c513302f) and was working well before, without any modification on my org or my Node server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found one part of the problem :

To by-pass some error with NodeJS security, I displayed the page with the Aura Lightning out using Chrome and a command disabling some security feature =>

[image]

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir="C:\Users\Johnny\Desktop\tempChrome"
```

But I think there were an update somewhere (NodeJS, Chrome or salesforce) that break diplaying Lightning Out in Chrome with thoses parameters.

**When I display my localhost in stardart Chrome, now it works (it doesn't weeks ago).**